# How to target an object property in geojson?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say we have a geojSon file structured like this:

```
     "type":"Feature",
     "id":"AFG",
     "properties":{
        "name":"Afghanistan"
     },
     "geometry":{
        "type":"Polygon",
        "coordinates":[
           [
              [
                 61.210817,
```

It has all countries so the file is quite big. How would I target one object which matches lets say "`France`" ? I need to be able to add a special class to the object I want to target.

**Note:** 
In reality it would be great if we could add classes to ***some countries*** so not a single object. Also each of these properties are `svg polygons`, so based on a name we need to add a class to that polygon.

Answer (score 0):

Found it via [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116159/how-to-style-specific-polygons-from-a-geojson-with-leaflet): Switch case!

```
var geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
    style: function(feature) {
        switch (feature.properties.name) {
            case 'Italia': return {fillColor: randomColor({hue: 'pink'})};
            case 'Russia':   return {fillColor: randomColor({hue: 'pink'})};
        }
    },
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

**UPDATE**

Actually the answer is on the [leaflet doc and tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/)

Comment: Note if the logic is the same for two values you can let the drop through, `case 'Italia': case 'Russia': return {fillColor: randomColor({hue: 'pink'});`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks you are right, I have also updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj={"type":"Feature",
     "id":"AFG",
     "properties":{"name":"Afghanistan"},
     "geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[61.210817,]]]}};

if(obj.properties.name == "France")
{
//Enter the code here.
}

And Followiing is for checking "Polygon".
obj.geometry.type  //Gives "Polygon" in this case
```